# How to show in my webpage files that are stores in different hard disks?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, hard-drive

I need to show information in my webpage built using PHP Zendframework that is stored in a server that has several hard disk.

So, I need to know how I can make accessible files that are in a different hard disk than the one in which the app is working (same server).

Normally you do something like /public/files/myfile.doc but you always are in the directory where the webpage is located. How can I do to have the same behavior but for files that are in different disks than the app?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Managing multiple HD in Zend app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36087246/managing-multiple-hd-in-zend-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post is not related to Zend Framework 2, just general linux filesystem issue. Can be solved with symlinks easy, just link any folder (with read access for web-server user) to /public:

```
ln -s /folder1 /public
```

or any /public subfolder:

```
ln -s /mnt/other_disk/folder2 /public/folders
```

Comment: great! Thanks! One extra questions... can I mount different folders to the same folder or I need to mount each folder to each other folder.. I mean something like:
ln -s /folder1 /public
ln -s /folder2 /public

or it should be 
ln -s /folder1 /public1
ln -s /folder2 /public2

maybe it is an stupid question.. maybe not.

Comment: This is not mounting, but linking, different things, but more organized way is to link folders into public folder as sub-folders, but there is no any restrictions :)

Comment: Thanks for your useful help!